# dropdown ListView not displaying in Android studio, but showing drop down icon

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-listfragment

I am trying to develop a listview drop down list, however, when I run the application I can only see the toolbar and then listview with arrow, however it does not show or display none of the listview options. please help.

Second.Java
public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

```
public ArrayList<GetterSetter> myArrayList;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private Spinner spinner;
ListView myList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(PlaceActivity.this, R.array.places, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

}



@Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);

    new readFromGooglePlaceAPI()
            .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                    + "location=53.795984,-1.759398&radius=100000&sensor=true&"
                    + "key=APIKey0&types="
                    + places[itemPosition]);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return true;


}
```

Second.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >


    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nodata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No data"
        android:textColor="#ff3b5998"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change your ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> to ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: This does not seem to work as <CharSequence> is fine.

Comment: okay you haven't created a new Instance of ArrayAdapter which is necessary. ArrayAdapter<CharSequenece/string> = new ArrayAdapter<Charsequence/String>(PlaceActivity.this, R.array.places, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)